# How to convert UIItem retrieved from GetMultiple to a concrete CustomUIItem in White?

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, white-framework

I have CustomUIItem implementation. In a window i have dynamically created N controls of this type.

```
class MyControlType : CustomUIItem{}
```

I need to get the list of all these controls:

```
var controls = window.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("MyControlType));
```

This returns me a list of all controls with such parameters:

```
ControlType = custom
CustomUIItem.AutomationId = MyControlType
```

Now i'd like to convert these custom controls to a concrete implementation MyControlType. How can i do that?

P.S. I've tried to cast to my type, e.g.

```
(MyControlType)control.
```

Also i've tried to create control manually:

```
new MyControlType(control.AutomationElement, control.ActionListener)
```

In this case Container property is null and i can't find inner controls.

Comment: Forgive me if I've misunderstood this, but just cast them? `(MyControlType)custom`

Comment: I don'T get it either, maybe provide more code? What Container property is null. I can't see one.

Comment: Generally speaking if you have a load of things, some of which may be your type, just loop through them casting and catch the InvalidCastExceptions, or loop through and use `MyControlType myControl = control as MyControlType;` and use a null check to avoid the ones that aren't. If something else is happening, more code please!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Code:

```
SearchCriteria.ByControlType(typeof(your_custom_control_type), WindowsFramework.Some_Framework)
```

when searching for the control. You'll be able to cast it to your_custom_control_type then.